How to convert binary I2C output of L76K GPS module to ascii symbols?
I write MicroPython code for my Raspberry Pi Pico. I faced the problem with converting bytes to the string. I receive the following data from the GPS module:
32

b'\x07\xe8\x05\x1f\t"\r,\x19\x00!0E\x19;\x01}\xf6N\x10\x00j\x14\x00\x00\x00\x01M_\x00 
\x039\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

It has to be convertible into ascii or unicode, but it doesn't seem to work.
The data should contain NMEA string and the garbage bytes have to be OA
This is my code:

from machine import Pin, I2C

def main() -> None:
    
  i2c_gps = I2C(0, scl=Pin(21), sda=Pin(20), freq=400000)
  print(i2c_gps.scan()[0])
  print(i2c_gps.readfrom(32, 50))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()

The hardware is: Pico W, GNSS positioning system from DFRobot based on L76K

I tried following the official documentation to decode the I2C package in a proper way, documentation, but I couldn't find anything to help me with that. All the other resources on the internet are related to either RPI 3 or 4 or to the UART standard. Github didn't contain the library as well. I'm new to embedded programming, I had electronics classes at my college but nobody taught us to work with I2C or any other protocol. Any help would be much appreciated.

It is clearly not a matter of "conversion", that data is simply not NMEA0183, there is no transformation that will make it so.  Either output is not NMEA, or your reading of the data is incorrect.

You have posted the data from the readfrom not not the scan call.  What did that output?

It is not a question of "conversion" but rather one of reading the device buffer correctly.
From the L76K documentation you linked, and the micropython I2C documentation, the following seems more likely.
i2c_gps.writeto(0x10, b'0')
buf = i2c_gps.readfrom( 0x10, 255 ) ;
print( buf )

Reading the buffer requires a proceeding dummy write, and the I2C class takes the unshifted 7-bit address, not the 8-bit address+R/nW flag used in the Quectel example code.  You should also read the entire buffer I think, otherwise you may get incomplete NMEA sentences and lose others completely.
Note that the so called "garbage" bytes can both proceed and follow the NMEA data.

Note about this answer.  I do not use micropython, I have never used this GNSS module.  I don't know if this will solve the problem, but I have read the documentation and I am sure this is closer to correct than the OP.

Hello! You asked me to post the full output. I updated my question

@InWamos interesting, my reading of the documentation and examples I would have expected 16 (0x10) as an address.  Nonetheless, the dummy write is still I think required.  If that does not work, always worth trying the 7bit address perhaps.

.scan() method already returns the 7-bit address

@InWamos the Quectel documentation says the 7-bit address is 0x10, and the scan is reporting 0x20.  I am only pointing out the ambiguity as an issue to investigate.  Address aside, you still have to do the dummy write.
